# ClearTool windows vs unix behaves different

Tags: cleartool

I used ClearCase/ClearTool several years ago in an unix env.
Now I'm in a Windows env.

The following unix `cleartool` command will display a version tree for each unit on my_branch all at once.
For example, if I have 5 units on my_branch, 5 version trees will be displayed at the same time:

```
find . -version 'version (.../my_branch/LATEST)' -exec 'cleartool lsvtree -g $CLEARCASE_PN'
```

I'm trying to do the same in Windows, however the following command displays a single version tree. Upon closing the version tree, the next version tree will be displayed:

```
find . -version 'version (.../my_branch/LATEST)' -exec 'cleartool lsvtree -g %CLEARCASE_PN%'
```

How do I get all version trees displayed at once in Windows?

Answer (score 0):

The [IBM addition example page](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21124425) proposes (for finding version with labels for instance):

```
cleartool find . -type f -exec "cleartool lsvtree -a %CLEARCASE_PN%" | findstr "("
```

The only difference seems to be the double quotes, but it does filter through each and every versions found.

Sale for protecting elements:

```
cleartool find . -all -name *.bat -print -exec "cleartool protect -chmod u+x -file ""%CLEARCASE_PN%"""
```

However, that triggers the command for each result, which might not be what you want.

---

If that still doesn't work, the other approach is to use the DOS `for` command:

```
for /f %a in ('cleartool find . -version 'version (.../my_branch/LATEST)'') do cleartool lsvtree -g %a
```

Again, I suspect the commands would be repeated sequencially.

---

The only way to achieve that on Windows would be to:

- put the find result in a text, making sure those versions are displayed in one line,
- then using the content of that file as parameter for your Windows `cleartool lsvtree -g`
  (since an `lsvtree` command can accept *several* `pname`), and see if then several graphical version tree are displayed at once.